# Jquery timer not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a timer in jquery that will persist when the page is refreshed and I'm having trouble. The timer works but when I refresh the page it disappears until the timer has reset from its initial 30 seconds and will appear again on refresh, I'm using this from a php file. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
var miliseconds = 30000;

function reset() {
localStorage.timer = +new Date + miliseconds;
}

if( ! localStorage.timer ) {
reset();
}

setInterval( function() {
var remaining = localStorage.timer - new Date;
if( remaining >= 0 ) {
    $('#timer').text( Math.floor( remaining / 1000 ) );
} else {
    reset();
}
}, 300 );</script>

<body>
<div>Will be ready in <span id="timer"></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I will try to help you if you can put it in a jsfiddle

Comment: The JavaScript does what it is supposed to do unless it is served from the PHP page, I assume.

Comment: @flaschiber Should I include this in its own file and use it that way? Rather then including this directly into the php file?

Comment: I added it into its own .js file and included it into the php file and it appears to be working, sorry for not trying that first.